# Multiply values in one cell and then summing it all?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

It's a confusing question but I will explain the best of my ability.

I'm trying to calorie count from my macro nutrients. One cell is the calories and one cell being the macro nutrients.

So my macro nutrient cell will be in this format: `231p / 157c / 62f`

"p" being protein(g), "c" being carbs(g), and "f" being fat(g).

1 gram of protein is 4 cals, 1 gram of carbs is 4 cals, and 1 gram of fat is 9 cals.

So my question is how do I multiply each number to their respective calories with grams and sum up the total to get the final total of calories in the other cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A2, "/"), "\d+")*
                  REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(B2, "/"), "\d+")))
```

[image: 0]